# Openshift deploy backend and frontend separately

Tags: deployment, openshift

I have an app on openshift. Currently backend and frontend are mixed up in a single WAR archive. 
Though I want to separate frontend and backend into 2 projects and deploy them seperately on the same node.

I haven't found anything in the openshift docs or on google.

Is there any way to accomplish that, or do I need to deploy backend and frontend separately onto 2 nodes?

Comment: What version of OpenShift are you talking about?

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript? Might be better asked at [DevOps](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97295/devops) or [sf], or maybe [webmasters.se], but you'll want to check their respective help centers first.

Comment: @graham it's the old web console (without github login). Is that sufficient? If not where can i look up the version number?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It's the easiest thing - to pack both backend and frontend as one jar. This requires you to have something like homepage controller (java/backend) which will serve the index.html. It's where you plug your frontend distribution css, js (bundled with webpack - nodejs/javascript world here). What you want then is to have a rest api (java) and index.html (served not by backend side) consuming that api (in spring boot you would set something like CrossOrigin annotation onto target api controller(-s)). Thus, this has to deal with app architecture.

Comment: @lexeme Unless you program OpenShift in JavaScript, the JavaScript tag is not appropriate on the question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan well, I don't think so. The point here is that both frontend and backend could be served by different webserver: Tomcat for Java-backend and Node.js-Express for frontend. This is quite possible. The question is how to do this - deploy them both - on OpenShift. Here javascript tag is a hint for a reader that frontend is something like Vue.js / Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use what is called a "node selector" to ensure a given object, in your case a deployment, is placed onto a specific node.

This behavior is outlined in the [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/nodes/scheduling/nodes-scheduler-node-selectors.html).

As per your request, this would allow you to split up your deployment, but have it land on the same node. However, it is not a pattern I would recommend. Relying on a specific node to exist, is not very failure tolerant. As such your frontend and backend should rather communicate via a `service` for example. This way, it doesn't matter where on your cluster frontend or backend are.